# Update state from separate component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have three components (parent, child, separate component).

In that **parent component** I have created a state values.

```
this.state = { 
  number: 1
}

<Child num={this.state.number} />
```

In **Child component** I have created a **Link to** from **react-router-dom**,

```
<Link to="goTo3rdComp" />
```

I want to update the parent state values from separate(3rd) component which is using **Link** from child component (without using redux or other state management approach.)

How can I pass the state through Link Tag and update the grant parent component.

**In short words:**
`<Parent /><Child /><3rdComponent /> are 3 components`. I dont want to update the parent state from child component. I want to update from 3rdComponent which is navigated by Link Tag/router-react-dom from child component .(i.e `<Link to="editpage" />`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass function to child which will update your parent component:

```
this.state = { 
  number: 1
}

<Child num={this.state.number} onChange={(newValue)=> this.setState({number: newValue})} />
```

And then in child do the next for example:

```
class Child extends Component{
  const { onChanage } = this.props;


  // run when you want...
  onChange(10);

}
```

Comment: <Parent /><Child /><3rdComponent /> are 3 components.
I dont want to update the state from child component. I want to update from 3rdComponent which is navigated by Link Tag/router-react-dom from child component .(i.e <Link to="editpage" />)